Error al ejecutar Chrome Web Driver con Selenium (Crash)
estoy teniendo un problema al intentar ejecutar Web Driver usando Selenium con Python. Tengo la Versión 126.0.6478.183 (Build oficial) (64 bits) de Chrome.
Cuando corro el siguiente código en vs code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://selenium.dev")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.quit()

Se abre el navegador de Chrome, realiza el get y luego se cierra, intenté ejecutar el programa sin driver.quit() pero se sigue crasheando y la verdad que no se me ocurren soluciones

Si el navegador se abre, espera a que se cargue la página y luego se cierra, entonces no es ningún "crash", es un comportamiento perfectamente normal y esperado.

driver.quit() explícitamente cierra todas las ventanas, termina la sesión de forma segura y destruye la instancia del driver.

Aun sin llamar a quit(), el proceso del navegador está asociado al de Python. La instancia de  webdriver.Chrome() será destruida tarde o temprano, bien por terminar el proceso o porque queda sin referencias y el GC la recolecta (por salir de ámbito, por ejemplo). En cualquier caso, esto hará que eventualmente la sesión del navegador también sea terminada.



Nota: téngase en cuenta que esto no es así para todos los
drivers, algunos navegadores permancen abiertos a no ser que se les diga lo contrario de forma
explícita, con quit() por ejemplo.

Si no quieres que se cierre, puedes intentar dos cosas:
Evitar que el script de Python termine
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://selenium.dev")

input("Pulse Enter para terminar")
driver.quit()

o con un tiempo de espera:
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://selenium.dev")

time.sleep(300) # 5 minutos
driver.quit()

Desacoplar el proceso de Python del driver
Esto se puede hacer con la opción detach y, obviamente, dejando de llamar a quit(). Ver la documentación:

Chrome specific functionality - Options
Funciones y opciones de Chrome - Objeto ChromeOptions


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("http://selenium.dev")


Hola, probé ese código y no soluciona el problema. Sin embargo, lo solucioné abriendo un NoteBook de Jyper y corre sin problemas. Debe ser un problema de vs code.

Hola @Elias, no uso VSCode pero detach  parece que no funciona en él, es algo conocido y es cosa de VSCode y no un problema del código o de selenium: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10658. Ejecutado a través del intérprete de CPython directamente o un intérprete interactivo, incluido jupyter/ipython funciona como debe.

Eso mismo intenté y pude solucionarlo. Gracias igualmente.
